# UITableViewCell iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have project(AppDelegate, ViewController and UITableViewCell).

//ViewController.m(Excerpt)

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
//====A====
    cell = [[TableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //====B==== //cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIView *bgView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.backgroundView = bgView;

    for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}

cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %i", @"row", indexPath.row];

if(indexPath.row % 2){
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}else{
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.1];
}

return cell;
}
```

//TableCell.m(UITableViewCell class)

```
  #import "TableCell.h"

NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

@implementation TableCell

@synthesize titleLabel;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])
    {

        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 320.0, 40.0);
        [self.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
        self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

`warning(initWithFrame:...iOS3)` is generated in the part //===A===. Therefore I write //===B===. Nothing in cell.
I want to get rid warning.

Comment: Override `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` instead of `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` and use former for creating the cell. Override `layoutSubviews` for positioning the cell content. There is not need to set table view cell's frame. That part is done by the datasource method.

Comment: I can if I use only reuseIdentifier:. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` is a deprecated method since iOS 3.0 (lot of time). Use the newer `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` and the warning will go away.

[UITableViewCell documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)